# How to trigger an action once the push notification is received

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to build an android app using java. I will use GCM to send push notifications. However, I am not sure if is it possible that we can use push notifications as a trigger. So I want to do something like this:

If a push notification is received from another device,
Make a boolean true,
Use this boolean and trigger an action.

I just want to find out if it is possible. I haven't start to code yet. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you should use FCM as [Google deprecated GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq).

Using FCM you can receive the notification and trigger an action in your device.

You'll need to register a service in your manifest:

```xml
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And then create the class `MyFirebaseMessagingService` that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` and override the `onMessageReceived` method:

```java
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Trigger any actions that you want.
}
```

For more information, please check the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=en).

Comment: Only problem with this is that onMessageReceived() is only triggered when the app is in foreground.